# Git source tree ignore indentation difference

Tags: git, version-control

In my company we use git source tree, the problem is that every developer has different indentation style, how we can disable this in source tree?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it's usually a good idea to define a style guide for projects so that all developers use the same style.

Comment: You need to use the same conventions. There are tools that can help you make a project uniform and further enforce it on every contribution. Uncrustify is one example. http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore whitespaces while merging changes:
git merge -Xignore-all-space